# Shadow in navbar and under navbar

Tags: css, less

I'm using [AdminLTE2](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) theme and I want to only have a drop shadow under my underNavBar (that has white background).

...I set z-index to overlap the box shadow of navbar, but if I set that  I do not see the dropdown of current users (figure 1).

On figure 2 we can see two box shadows, because I'm using navbar in other pages two without underNavBar.

[image: No shadow, but overlapping]

[image: Navbar and under navbar have both shadows]

```css
    .navbar-static-top {
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
                -box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    }

    .navbar-custom-menu>.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
        padding-top: 0px;
        border-style: none;
    }

    .nav {
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
                -box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
                -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
                -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
                -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
                -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
                -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
                user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                          supported by Chrome and Opera */
            }

    .navbar-static-action-bar {
                display: table;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                background-color: @action-primary;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1031;
            }
```

Comment: can you upload your code

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: I add css styling